# Register ActiveX Control without an ocx file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, activex

I am adding functionality to an open source project which uses an external activex control known as DMGraph (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310494/D-Graph-ActiveX-Control-in-Cplusplus-with-ATL-No-M?msg=4567275#xx4567275xx) but I get an error that the control needs to be registered when I try opening the resource file that uses this control. As stated on the project page that I linked, there is no ocx file, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to register this control without said file. If its any help to finding the issue, I have simply downloaded the source code to this open source project that i'm trying to get this work in. It has already implemented the DMGraph functionality and works in their builds so the issue must be with trying to build it on a different machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Why was this downvoted. I'd like some feedback rather than getting this question buried.

Comment: Can't you just register the DLL?  It looks like the author answered a question about that

Comment: As Jim Hewitt said, register the control with RegSvr32.exe. I don't know what the output from building the source is but it might be a dll. Actually, building the source might do the registration for you. All registering the control does is write some stuff about the ActiveX control in the registy.